# Azure Active Directory Group - controlling user access

Tags: active-directory, azure-active-directory, active-directory-group, adgroup

I have a requirement to add users to an Azure Active Directory group with certain privileges.

For example, specific user added to `adgroup1` gets edit access on application specific data, while the same user could be part of `adgroup2` with read only access for different set of application data.

What would be the best practice to implement this? Appreciate the feedback.

Comment: I think the data granularity is too small, it is difficult to control, how about write/read all the applications in the tenant?

Comment: It’s single application access but different sets of data ...is there any attributes available while adding a user to an ad group so we can set it as read or write?

Comment: Well, any sample for `different sets of data`? And just concern if the `application` in your question is the `App registration` in AAD?

Comment: Yes, application is app registered in AAD.   User1 -> adGroup1 -> Data1 -> edit access , User2 -> adGroup2 -> Data1 -> view access.. I am looking for a user specific attribute that can be set when adding the user to an ad group that is applicable only from that ad group context. thanks!

Comment: Any other concerns about this issue?

Comment: Fine grained entitlements are implemented as data driven instead of AD roles

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am afraid this could not be implemented, in Azure AD, a normal user (i.e. `User type` is `member`) has the default permissions to **view** all the AD Apps in the tenant, source [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/fundamentals/users-default-permissions#compare-member-and-guest-default-permissions).

[image]

This could not be restricted, default permissions for member users can be restricted list [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/fundamentals/users-default-permissions#restrict-member-users-default-permissions), even if you set `Restrict access to Azure AD administration portal`, the user can also get the information from other clients e.g. powershell.

For the **edit** permission, the user needs to be added as an [`Owner`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/roles/delegate-app-roles#assign-application-owners) to the AD App, but the `AAD group` is not supported to be added as an `Owner` to the AD App.